# Is it necessary to say $x$ is an integral element of $L$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, extension-field

[image: page 12 of Neukirch]

In the above picture, there is a sentence as follows:

> If $x\in B$ is an integral element of $L$, then all of its conjugates $\sigma x$ are  also integral.

If $x\in B$, then all of its conjugates $\sigma x$ are also integral (over $A$).
Thus it is not necessary to say $x$ is an integral element of $L$, it suffices to state it as follows:

> If $x\in B$, then all of its conjugates $\sigma x$ are  also integral.

Is my viewpoint correct?

Comment: What you're saying makes sense but the sentence you quote sounds awful; I would much rather read the one given in the text. It is always better to reiterate, lest the reader forget what role $B$ plays.

Comment: @ÍgjøgnumMeg Ok.